# Increment the value of the map if key is already present?

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a map in which I am storing total number of bytes as the key and count as the value. I need to increment the count by 1 if the key is already present in my map. If the key is not present then start with 1.

I have the below code -

```
Map<Integer, Integer> userList = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
for (String userId : listOfUsers) {
        String sql = "select * from test_table where user_id='"+ userId + "';";
    try {
        SimpleStatement query = new SimpleStatement(sql);
        ResultSet res = session.execute(query);

        int totalBytes = 0;
        Iterator<Row> rows = res.iterator();
        while (rows.hasNext()) {
            Row r = rows.next();

            ByteBuffer client_value = r.getBytes("client_value");

            int returned = client_value.remaining();
            totalBytes = totalBytes + returned;
        }

        // does this look right?
        userList.put(totalBytes, userList.get(totalBytes) + 1);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log an error
    }
}
```

Whenever I am running for the first time, I am getting NPE on my `userList.put` command. Is there anything wrong I am doing? This code will be in single thread.

Comment: How about trying your code? It will tell you what is wrong with it. Oh no, it won't: catch (Exception e) {
        // log an error
    }

Comment: Does it *work* right? If so then there isn't a better way. Test it, with and without the key already existing in the map. You'll then quickly identify the problem with it (hint: yes, there is a problem).

Comment: Sorry I just updated now, it is throwing NPE on userList.put command. I should have posted it after running. Sorry about that.

Comment: @david If it throws an NPE then it isn't right. For that, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it, which will provide you with the info you need to add the logic to make sure that doesn't happen.

Comment: @david The logic implemented by the put(n, get(n)+1) is very curious, especially when one considers how this value n is composed, i.e., from a sum of bytes remaining in a ByteBuffer. There is no way to relate this value to any "solid" value in the data, such as a user id.

Comment: @laune looks like it is constructing a frequency table of "total client value size by user", which might be useful for statistical purposes.

Comment: As a sidenote, the counting idiom you are trying to implement is done much better with a multimap: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained

Comment: @The111 "Counting" is not the same as "storing", so multimap isn't applicable here.

Comment: @laune It is not clear to me what OP is accomplishing with his code conceptually (though he does use the word "count" in his first sentence).  But **logically** he is mapping a key to a value which represents a count, which is precisely the situation described in the link above, and precisely something a multimap excels at, saving him the null checks and increments he is doing (possibly at the cost of more complex logic when reading from the map later, but again I'm not sure what he is ultimately using the map for).

Comment: @The111 The key is a length (in bytes), the value is the frequency this length occurs. What do you want to store in the Collection that is the value of a multimap? The Integer 1, many times???

Comment: @laune Oops I meant multiset, sorry for the confusion and (twice) wrong term typed in my comments.

Comment: @The111 Yes, you can store all lengths as they occur in a multiset. Although I don't see why keeping the very many counted items (integers!) should be superior to keeping their occurrence count: Why is {1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3} better than {<1:6>,<2:8>,<3:7>}?

Comment: @laune That's an implementation detail, and most multiset implementations use a backing map rather than actually storing multiple copies of identical objects as you seem to imply.  In either case you are conceptually storing {<key:count>, <key:count>, etc}.  The reason to use the multiset interface is because it allows you to write more succint and error-free code, again as described much more thoroughly at the page I linked a few posts up.

Comment: Come to think of it, neither form is perfect. What you need is some class `Frequency<T>` with `count(T item)` and assorted methods. The Map code on that page isn't best practice (any more), and obtaining the results isn't compared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if the key is not already present you'll get a `NullPointerException`. That's because the expression `userList.get(totalBytes) + 1` will try to unbox the `null` to an `int`.

The correct way would be to do a `null` check before addition.

```
Integer bytes = userList.get(totalBytes);
userList.put(totalBytes, bytes == null ? 1 : bytes + 1);
```

Comment: I believe it would be better to encourage the OP to actually run and test his code and discover this.

Comment: @david Just do a `null` check before you try to increment the value as shown in my answer.

Comment: @david To fix: Check the documentation of `get()`, see that it returns `null` when the element isn't found, observer that `null + 1` throws an NPE, then add logic to insure that `null + 1` never happens. You describe your desired behavior as *"I need to increment the count by 1 if the key is already present in my map. If the key is not present then start with 1."*, but you did not implement the second sentence of that description. :) Your description pretty much directly translates into the logic you need.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal I need to find out how many users have 100 bytes, how many users have 200 bytes of data so that's why I am storing totalBytes as the key and total count as the value.

Answer (score 1):

No,

```
userList.put(totalBytes, userList.get(totalBytes) + 1);
```

The first tiem that you run this, the `userList.get(totalBytes)` will return a null object which of course can not be incremented.

It can be fixed as

```
Integer val = userList.get(totalBytes);
if (val == null) {
   val = new Integer ();
}
val = val + 1;
```

Comment: I believe it would be better to encourage the OP to actually run and test his code and discover this.

Comment: @ScaryWombat I found out the issue when I ran it. I added the comments in my question as well. i should have waited before posting the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can change

```
userList.put(totalBytes, userList.get(totalBytes) + 1);
```

to

```
userList.put(totalBytes, userList.getOrDefault(totalBytes, 0) + 1);
```

if you're using Java 8, eliminating the need for manual null-checks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below..

```
userList.put(totalBytes,(userList.contains(totalBytes)?(userList.get(totalBytes)+1):1));
```